# Change hostname for single application on linux

Tags: linux, hostname

I want the computer to appear to have a different name for some application (that doesn't have a GUI, if that makes it any easier) without actually changing the name.

I don't want a virtual machine though, as said application is computationally expensive.

Comment: This is not possible.

Comment: Smells like a XY question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change hostname. But you can add in your /etc/hosts or in DNS additional hostnames assigned to your hosts IP.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your hostname (see https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-change-hostname/ for a simple documentation with samples for numerous distributions).
But I don't know any way to change the hostname just for one application.

One thing that may work if the application is registering the hostname on launch, is:

1. Change the hostname with "hostname [theHostnameYouWant]"
2. Launch the application.
3. Change the hostname back.